# Asserting against handled exceptions in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

I have a method that takes a JSON object and puts it through several stages of processing, updating values in the database at each stage. We wanted this method to be fault tolerant, and decided that the desired behaviour would be, if any processing stage failed, log an error to the database and carry on with the next stage of processing, rather than aborting.

I've just made several changes to the behaviour of one of the processing steps. I then ran our unit test suite, expecting several of the tests to fail due to the new behaviour and point me at potential problem areas. Instead, the tests all passed.

After investigating, I realised that the mock data the tests run against didn't include certain key values important for the new behaviour. The tests were in fact throwing exceptions when they ran, but the exceptions were being caught and handled - and, because the tests don't run with a logger enabled, they were completely suppressed. So the new code didn't change the data in a way that would cause the tests to fail, because it was silently erroring instead.

This seems like the sort of problem that unit tests are there to catch, and the fact that they showed no trace means they're not serving their purpose. Is there any way that I can use NUnit to assert that no exception was ever thrown, even if it was handled? Or alternatively, is there a sensible way to refactor that would expose this issue better?

(Working in C#, but the question seems fairly language-agnostic)

Comment: Not really, the behaviour of the functions tested remained the same before and after the changes (as far as the callers are concerned) therefore all tests passed. If you introduce new side effects, you should also write unit tests. In your case, I guess it's difficult to test error logging, but I suppose since you can predict execution path, you know how many times logger will be called, so you can use some mock logger and assert that mock logger was called expected number of times.

Comment: The expected behavior of your class is that it should catch certain exceptions and log them. You can't test catching an exception. You can only test what a class does - results it returns, changes to its state, and effects it causes. In this case you want to test the effect the code produces, which is output to a log. That means you have to mock the log. It can be as easy as creating an implementation of the log that adds the message to a list. If you include some code that shows how you call the logger (is it injected) then we can provide more detail.

Comment: It is injected, I've just used NSubstitute to create a subbed logger that throws an exception whenever its `LogError` function is called, and now most of my tests are failing! Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, in the scenario you describe, the presence or absence of exceptions is secondary. If you wrote the code to produce a desired result while catching and handling exceptions, then that result - whether it's a return value or some other effect - is the most important thing to test.

If the exceptions that you didn't see caused that result to be incorrect, then testing for the correct result will always reveal the problems. If you don't know what the expected result will be and are only interested in whether or not exceptions are getting handled, something is wrong. We can never determine whether or not anything works correctly according to whether or not it throws exceptions.

That aside, here's how to test whether or not your code is catching and logging exceptions that you wouldn't otherwise be able to observe:

If you're injecting a logger that looks something like this:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogError(Exception ex);
    void LogMessage(string message);
}
```

...then a simple approach is to create a test double which stores the exceptions so that you can inspect it and see what was logged.

```
public class ListLoggerDouble : ILogger
{
    public List<Exception> Exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    public List<string> Messages = new List<string>();

    public void LogError(Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.Add(ex);
    }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Messages.Add(message);
    }
}
```

After you've executed the method you're testing you can assert that a collection contains the exception(s) or message(s) you expect. If you wish you can also verify that there are none, although it seems like that might be redundant if the result you're testing for is correct.

---

I wouldn't create a logger that throws an exception and then write a test that checks for a thrown exception. That makes it look like the expected behavior of your code is to throw an exception, which is exactly the opposite of what it does. Tests help us to document expected behaviors. Also, what will you do if you want to verify that you caught and logged two exceptions?

Comment: It's more that I've created a logger that throws an exception to cause the test to fail if an exception is thrown, because those tests shouldn't be throwing exceptions

Comment: I understand. But the result is that you've got a class that wouldn't throw exceptions under normal circumstances, and a test that asserts that it *does* throw an exception. Meanwhile the actual expected behavior of the class - that it logs the exception - *isn't* tested.